# jQuery JSON data is not defined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to jQuery & I noticed that `jsondata` has an error of *ReferenceError: jsondata is not defined*

here is my jquery:

```
$('#btnLogin').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/User/LogOn',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    username: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                    password: $('#txtPassword').val()
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    var jsondata = data;
                    if (jsondata == "true") {
                        window.location = "/Message/SendMessage";
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {

                    alert(error);

                }
            });
        });
```

And here is my C#:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(User model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, true);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    Response.Write("true");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "User");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Please help... And Thank you in advance

Comment: jQuery will already have parsed the response to a JS object for you, so you don't need the `var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);` line.

Comment: I've made that change and still getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified the datatype as json, no need for `parseJson` there.
Try

```
success: function (data) {
                var jsondata = data;
                if (jsondata == "true") {
                    window.location = "/Message/SendMessage";
                }
            },
```

**Edit**
The method corresponding to your ajax call should be look like,

```
public Returntype LogOn(string username,string password)
{

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The LogOn method is returning an ActionResult type. If your sure your returning the data, try and change it to JsonResult and on the return line do:

```
return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```